# Parsing Date time in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Below is the date format for the 'date' field, which I'm getting from API to Bigquery as a string.
2020-09-17T00:00:00+03:00
I want to parse the date format to '%Y%m%d' and then extract it as ISOWEEK.
This is the code I came up with;

```
EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM PARSE_DATETIME("%Y%m%d", REGEXP_EXTRACT(date, r"...................")))
```

However, this gives me an error.
Could you guide me what needs change?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the steps here. The date input is a string of a date in a certain timezone (+03:00), for example `"2020-09-17T00:00:00+03:00"`. Then on this string you can apply:

- Keep the date on the correct timezone

```sql
DATE("2020-09-17T00:00:00+03:00", "+03:00")
```

- Format the date with the desired format in a string

```sql
FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", DATE("2020-09-17T00:00:00+03:00", "+03:00"))
```

- Parse the date from the previously formatted string

```sql
PARSE_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", DATE("2020-09-17T00:00:00+03:00", "+03:00")))
```

- Finally extract the ISOWEEK from the date

```sql
EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM PARSE_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", DATE("2020-09-17T00:00:00+03:00", "+03:00"))))
```

So, this will give you the result you want.

```sql
select EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM PARSE_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", DATE(date))))
```

You can also skip the "%Y/%m/%d" if it's not really helping you with something else and simply do

```sql
select EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM DATE("2020-09-17T00:00:00+03:00", "+03:00"))
```

which results to the same thing